# VB.NET Browserview.Document.InvokeScript()

Tags: html, .net, vb.net

Hello I am very new so try to be nice, :) 
I have no explanation as to the behavior I am noticing, so thought I would ask. I have googled this and could spend hours trying to figure it out. I have created this to simplify a larger project and it has the same behavior. I am trying to execute a Javascript function from this form. I am able to do it on the button press but it will not work on the load function. Same function but it only executes on the button click event. I would like it to work on the Form Load rather than the button.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub InvokeTestMethod(ByVal Name As Single, ByVal Address As 
Single)
    If (Not (WebBrowser1.Document Is Nothing)) Then
        Dim ObjArr(2) As Object
        ObjArr(0) = Name
        ObjArr(1) = Address
        WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("test", ObjArr)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    InvokeTestMethod(1, 2)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object,
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("C:\Users\Trent\source\repos\WindowsApp2\WindowsApp2\HTMLPage1.html")
    InvokeTestMethod(1, 2)
End Sub
End Class


<HTML>
<head>
    <SCRIPT>
        function test(name, address) {
            window.alert("Name is " + name + "; address is " + address);
        }
    </SCRIPT>
</head>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: `.Navigate` behaves in an asynchronous fashion - it starts navigating and returns immediately (before the page is loaded). As a consequence if you run code after calling it either you act on the stale current document or there is no loaded document at all. Call your code in the document complete event as at that point the page DOM is available for you to play with.

Comment: Perfect. Thankyou for the response. :)